# What is the difference and how to choose between distributed queue and distributed computing platform?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, distributed, distributed-computing

there are many files need to process with two computers real-timely,I want to distribute them to the two computers and these tasks need to be completed as soon as possibile(means real-time processing),I am thinking about the below plan:

(1) distributed queue like Gearman

(2）distributed computing platform like hadoop/spark/storm/s4 and so on

I have two questions

（1）what is the advantage and disadvantage between (1) and (2)?

（2) How to choose in (2),hadoop?spark?storm?s4?or other?

thanks!

Maybe I have not described the question clearly. In most case,there are 1000-3000 files with the same format , these files are independent,you do not need to care their order,the size of one file maybe tens to hundreds of KB and in the future, the number of files and size of single file will rise. I have wrote a program , it can process the file and pick up the data and then store the data in mongodb. Now there are only two computers, I just want a solution that can process these files with the program quickly（as soon as possibile） and is easy to extend and maintain

distributed queue is easy to use in my case bur maybe hard to extend and maintain , hadoop/spark is to "big" in the two computers but easy to extend and maintain, which is better, i am confused.

Comment: Real-time processing does not mean the tasks have to be completed as soon as possible. If your data changes all the time and you want to have tasks always running on old + new data, then you'd need real time processing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the nature of your "processing". Some dimensions that apply here are:

1. Are records independent from each other or you need some form of aggregation? i.e: do you need some pieces of data to go together? Say, all transactions from a single user account.
2. Is you processing CPU bound? Memory bound? FileSystem bound?
3. What will be persisted? How will you persist it?
4. Whenever you see new data, do you need to recompute any of the old?
5. Can you discard data?
6. Is the data somewhat ordered?
7. What is the expected load?

A good solution will depend on answers to these (and possibly others I'm forgetting). For instance:

1. If computation is simple but storage and retrieval is the main concern, you should maybe look into a distributed DB rather than either of your choices.
2. It could be that you are best served by just logging things into a distributed filesystem like HDFS and then run batch computations with Spark (should be generally better than plain hadoop).
3. Maybe not, and you can use Spark Streaming to process as you receive the data.
4. If order and consistency are important, you might be better served by a publish/subscribe architecture, especially if your load could be more than what your two servers can handle, but there are peak and slow hours where your workers can catch up.

etc. So the answer to "how you choose?" is "by carefully looking at the constraints of your particular problem, estimate the load demands to your system and picking the solution that better matches those". All of these solutions and frameworks dominate the others, that's why they are all alive and kicking. The choice is all in the tradeoffs you are willing/able to make.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe I have not described the question clearly. In most case,there are 1000-3000 files with the same format , these files are independent,you do not need to care their order,the size of one file maybe tens to hundreds of KB and in the future, the number of files and size of single file will rise. I have wrote a program , it can process the file and  pick up the data and then store the data in mongodb. Now there are only two computers, I just want a solution that can process these files with the program quickly（as soon as possibile） and is easy to extend and maintain.

Comment: distributed queue is easy to use in my case bur maybe hard to extend and maintain , hadoop/spark is to "big" in the two computers but easy to extend and maintain, which is better, i am confused.

Comment: Mmm, 2 machines is kind of a gray area. Going from single-machine to fully-distributed involves a significant extra serialization and coordination effort. You might not see much of an improvement (maybe even be slower). Say, once you have processed a file, do you need to update or process it again or you are basically done and only new files are coming in?

Comment: these files are coming together almost at the same time, once i have processed a file ,the program will store the data into database,I do not need to update or process it again,just process the next file and do the same job.A few minutes later，another batch of files will come and I need do the same job above. Maybe one computer is enough, but another computer is idle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dannyhow is right - this is not what real-time processing is about. There is a great book http://www.manning.com/marz/ which says a lot about lambda archtecture.

The two ways you mentioned serves completly different purposes and are connected to the definition of word "task". For example, Spark will take a whole job you got for him and divide it into "tasks", but the outcome of one task is useless for you, you still need to wait for whole job to finish. You can create small jobs working on the same dataset and use spark's caching to speed it up. But then you won't get much advantage from distribution (if they have to be run one after another).

Are the files big? Are there connected somehow to each other? If yes, I'd go with Spark. If no, distributed queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe I have not described the question clearly. In most case,there are 1000-3000 files with the same format , these files are independent,you do not need to care their order,the size of one file maybe tens to hundreds of KB and in the future, the number of files and size of single file will rise. I have wrote a program , it can process the file and pick up the data and then store the data in mongodb. Now there are only two computers, I just want a solution that can process these files with the program quickly（as soon as possibile） and is easy to extend and maintain

Comment: distributed queue is easy to use in my case bur maybe hard to extend and maintain , hadoop/spark is to "big" in the two computers but easy to extend and maintain, which is better, i am confused

Comment: If your job is just to store the data in db, think about using Impala instead of mongo and then just apply AVRO schema to your files. This is EXTREMLY fast.